# Switching regulator to power motor

Tags: power, motor, voltage-regulator, switch-mode-power-supply

I am trying to power my servomotor only for a short period of time (controlled by my MCU). I have seen I could use a switching regulator (3 pins). The thing is that I am working with really low power. The battery provides 3.6V to 4.2V; My MCU works with 3.3V and my motor needs 3.5V to 6.4V.

Do you have a solution to power my motor with this kind of switching regulator?

Comment: I think you are referring to PWM more than switching regulator (as in SMPS)

Comment: IF you mean that the motor can run on any voltage from 3.5 to 6.4 then Vbattery of 3.6 to 4.2 is always in the range and you do not need a regulator.

Comment: You must tell us what max motor current is and whether anv voltage from 3.5-6.4 is OK or if you MUST have eg 6.0 on occasions.

Comment: I didn't measure the max motor current (I need to learn how to make a PWM before). I want to use the switch in order to stop powering the motor (sleeping mode for few months).

Comment: With all due respect to Russell, but why did you accept his answer? It's just a copy of stevenvh's who posted earlier, and Russell doesn't even mention shutdown, which you seem to need.

Comment: I have tried to accept but I think I have done a wrong manipulation, I need to shutdown that's true

Comment: @Federico - I cannot understand why you have ignored the part of my anser labelled (1). Usually (1) would be considered a primary response, (2) a secondary one etc. | Mattew's requirement is still unclear BUT if his latest comment of "I would like to find a module which could provide 3.6V or 0 only when I send a command from my MCU." is taken at face value then my (1) applies and my (2) doesn't and Steven's doesn't. ie work in progress which I was and still am trying to resolve to his satisfaction. | Shutdown can follow once we REALLY know what is actually wanted.

Comment: Mattew - it is important that you make it clear what voltages are acceptable for your motor. If you want either 3.6V or 0V and no other voltages then this can be done with a simple linear regulator. Please advise - Is 3.6V the only voltage you need for your motor when it is turned on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**(1) NO regulator needed?**

IF you mean that the motor can run on any voltage from 3.5 to 6.4 then Vbattery of 3.6 to 4.2 is always in the range and **you do not need a regulator**. ie

- Vbat_min < Vmotor_Min < Vbat_max < Vmotor_max

**(2) Buck Boost:**

If you mean that you want to be able to set a motor voltage anywhere in the range 3.5V to 6.4V at any time regardless of battery voltage then you need a buck-boost converter. A boost only or buck only converter will not work in all cases.

If maximum efficiency is not crucial (and it may not be for 3 seconds of opoeration) Then the 48 cents MC34063 [data sheet here](http://www.st.com/internet/com/TECHNICAL_RESOURCES/TECHNICAL_LITERATURE/DATASHEET/CD00001232.pdf) will do your job. See fig 17 for one of several ways to achieve buck boost - efficiency can be better than what they say.

For better efficincy the eg TPS63060 is an example of an IC that uses syncronous rectification [data sheet here](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps63060.pdf) About $4/1 at Digikey.  This can provide over 1A out in buck or boost mode.

Example circuit only:

[image]

Comment: Things look like I need to find a DC/DC Converter module all included. I would like to find a module which could provide 3.6V or 0 only when I send a command from my MCU. Do you know where could I find these modules ?

Answer (score 3):

Your input range is very close to the output voltage and then a buck/boost regulator is useful.

[image]

[This one](http://cds.linear.com/docs/Datasheet/3538fb.pdf) has a 95 % efficiency and a 5 \$\mu\$A shutdown mode. You set the output voltage with the resistor divider R1/R2. Note: this comes in a small package, which may or not may be an advantage.

Anyway, there are many buck/boost converters with an enable input. You'll find a list from Linear Technologies [here](http://parametric.linear.com/internal_power_switch_buck-boost#!1646_Buck-Boost|SEPIC!1032_%3C=3!1033_%3E=5!1105_%3C=3.6!1034_%3E=3.6!1035_0.33:3.96!1107_0.1:1.2!vinmin_3!vinmax_5!vout_3.6!iout_0.1).

Comment: Thank you very much. I am using a LIPO battery, do you think I can use the same system. I also need to be careful to the size (really small device). Thank you.

Comment: Your not getting my upvote for anything short of 99% efficiency. Let me know when corrected :)~

Comment: @Mattew, your comments are signed by you, actually,  everything on the site you do will have a signature of some sort from you, there is no need to ever had a signature. If you want to thank him give him an upvote(when you have the rep) or accept his answer if it is the best.

Comment: Wow, that is expensive, as all of the LT parts :) $5 in 100qty!

Comment: @Mattew - It indicates Li-Ion/Li-Polymer, so that should be perfect, I presume 800 mA will be sufficient? Replacing R1 with a 600k will give you 4 V out. I wouldn't go too high as it will only increase power consumption.

Comment: @abdullah - Linear is expensive, but they have the best parts, and the best support. When one of my colleagues started working with switchers for the first time they sent an FAE over from Germany to give us a one day masterclass on the topic.

Comment: @stevenvh WOW! That is GREAT support! I can't believe it!

Comment: @abdullah - You better believe it, 'coz it's true :-). That at least partly explains the higher price; those FAEs have to eat too ;-). (FAEs are a free service by a distributor or manufacturer.) At a professional level good support may save you lots of design problems, and then the higher component price pays itself back.

Comment: @stevenvh Well, I don't think we have any FAEs in Turkey, yet. By the way, do you have to buy from LT if you "use" their FAEs?

Comment: @abdullah - If you buy very little from them they'll be less enthousiast ;-). Usually when a new project starts with high production quantities they're very keen to give you support to get the order. It partly works, purchasing is mostly interested in price and lead times, but I can influence their purchase decision by explaining I got this great support from distributor X. Turkey has them too, the slogan of EBV (one of the largest distri's) is "distribution is worldwide".

Comment: @stevenvh Nah, their FAEs know nothing but the parameters of the ICs.. In Turkey, FAE = Marketer with EE degree.

Comment: Things look like I need to find a DC/DC Converter module all included. I would like to find a module which could provide 3.6V or 0 only when I send a command from my MCU. Do you know where could I find these modules ?